# In JMeter based on the response from previous request need to have dynamic input in next request

Tags: jmeter

Currently i am sending a request in JMeter and response for same is a page with a Form. Here i need to input a value from csv but the problem is the response will be different and dynamic everytime and I need to read the response and input correct value for respective response received. Is it possible and how can we read the correct input eveytime from csv dynamically and input the same

Comment: You can use (JMeter post-processors )[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors]to extract values from responses. Can you provide a sample response?

Comment: Reading a response is fine, after that do we need to add condition to validate the same and how to read csv dynamically based on the response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CSV provides necessary functionality, if you have a dynamic response and would like to use it as a "key" for retrieving value from the CSV file - you will have to go for [Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) scripting.

Better/easier option would be storing your key/value combinations in:

1. A [relative DB](https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/relation-data-model/) and use [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) for extracting the dynamic data based on the key provided
2. In a key/value storage like [Redis](https://redis.io/) and use [Redis Data Set](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) for the same